# How to create a basic user login/register with mongdb

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mongodb

I have been using MVC3 for quite some time now and I just started getting into mongoDB.  Up until now, I have been using the basic MembershipProvider system provided when you create a basic web application in visual studio.  I have not built my own before.  I understand this generates the schema for you (dbo.aspnet_Users and dbo.aspnet_Membership), but a lot of it is extraneous.  Is there a tutorial out there in order to get a basic login/register system that reads directly from mongodb.. would this even be a good idea? or would i keep my users in a seperate sql database and all my other data in mongodb?

Comment: There are couple of .NET Membership providers custom implementation which uses MongoDB as the backend DB. One such implementation is here [GitHub](https://github.com/alanning/MongoProviders)

Answer (score 0):

I would keep the users with all the rest of your data. If you have a users collection, I think a sample document would look like this:

User:

```
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("507f1f77bcf86cd799439011"),
   "username" : "bob123",
   "password" : "ABC122939232DEFEFE",
   "status" : "active", // could be "pending" or whatever
   "email" : "bob@gmail.com"
}
```

You give the user a register screen where they create a login name and a password. You might consider making them use their email as a login - pretty standard these days.

Make sure *not* to store their password in plain text. Instead you run it through a hash function and store that result (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function). When they login in, you take the password entered and hash it, then compare it to the value in the database. Always have to plan for the unfortunate situation that someone steals your database. =(

Then you can also manage their status with a flag in the user document. You can make people confirm their email by sending them a link and having them visit it.

Just some ideas from what I've done in the past with simple logins.

Comment: thanks so much for a great reply, if i could ask a step further, how would one connect the mongoDB to the FormsAuthentication so that in my code i can call things like `Membership.GetUser().ProviderKey` and use the `[Authorize]` attribute

Comment: Adding onto @ryan1234 answer, you could use [BCrypt.Net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BCrypt-Official) to hash passwords.